# is there a limit to the size of a SKSpriteNode() texture? (4000 x 4000)

Tags: sprite-kit, textures, sprite

I have been adding textures to SKSpriteNode() and also getting the texture from nodes in order to change them.
When adding textures I can't add a texture over 4000 wide or high without it resulting in a black SKSpriteNode() (the texture exists, its just black)
When getting a texture from a node I have to make sure the result is within 4000 width or height by scaling the node before getting the texture otherwise it is blank again.

This is all fine for my game at the moment but I am wondering if there is an inbuilt limit of 4000, just so I can allow for it.
(there is a reason why I am using such large textures...so it is possible that I might go over 4000 width occasionally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this helpful chart from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/metal/limits/

It has a lot of information about graphical limitations. If you want to know the maximum texture size for iOS, find the entry for **"Maximum 2D texture width and height"**.

It depends on what operating systems you are targeting. For example, if you want to support iOS 8 and higher you are restricted to the iOS 8 limit for 2D textures of 4096 x 4096 pixels even though later versions of iOS can support larger textures.